# Is it considered an API or ABI break in C/C++ to add to a struct defined in a public header file of a library, but never passed to the library itself?

Tags: c++, c, struct, api-design, abi

I am designing a C/C++ API for a static/shared library that wraps around platform-specific file dialog APIs.  It supports multiple platforms, but intends to present an identical API for all platforms.  It is a C API, but like most C APIs, the header is wrapped in `extern "C"` and is intended to be callable directly in C++ code.

Typical file dialogs have many properties you can set on them before showing the dialog, such as file filters, titles, current folder, pre-filled filename, and parent window (there are many more obscure properties that can be set too).  A user will usually set just a few of these properties, and leave the rest to platform defaults (e.g. the default current folder might be `Documents` on Windows, and the title will be "Open File" or the equivalent in the system language).

Because there are many properties that can be set, and additional properties may become available for customization in the future, a simple API like

```c
/// Opens a file dialog and blocks until the user closes it.  `result` will contain the selected file.  The other parameters are properties that can be used to customize the file dialog; or set to NULL to use the system default.
bool OpenFile(const char** result, Filter* filter_list, size_t filter_count, const char* title, const char* current_folder, bool modal, const char* parent_window);
```

does not seem ideal because of two reasons:

- Most users will want the platform-specific defaults for most properties, so we will end up with a call like `OpenFile(&result, list, 4, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL)`, which is long and it isn't clear which properties each of the `NULL`s represent.
- It is inextensible; if I support a new property, I'll have to add a new function like `OpenFile_v2(...)` and so on.

---

I'm considering this alternative API instead (shown code goes into header file included by both my library and user code):

```c
typedef struct {
    const char** result = NULL;
    Filter* filter_list = NULL;
    size_t filter_count = 0;
    const char* title = NULL;
    const char* current_folder = NULL;
    bool modal = true;
    const char* parent_window = NULL;
    /* more fields might be added here in the future so this struct should not be passed across an ABI boundary */
} OpenFileProperties;
bool OpenFile(OpenFileProperties props) {
    // This calls some library functions in some order supported by the library
    // perhaps `parent_window` is needed by the platform native API at the point of construction of the file dialog
    void* handle = OpenFile_Impl_New(props.parent_window);
    if (filter_count) OpenFile_Impl_SetFilterList(handle, props.filter_list, props.filter_count);
    if (title) OpenFile_Impl_SetTitle(handle, props.title);
    if (current_folder) OpenFile_Impl_SetCurrentFolder(handle, props.current_folder);
    // `result` and `modal` are passed together here due to the shape of the platform native API
    return OpenFile_Impl_Show(handle, props.result, props.modal);
}

/* APIs to set individual properties - while these are stable, users should not use them directly because the functions may need to be called in a specific order!  These are implemented by my library (e.g. `OpenFile.c`). */
void* OpenFile_Impl_New(const char* parent_window);
void OpenFile_Impl_SetFilterList(void* handle, Filter* filter_list, size_t filter_count);
void OpenFile_Impl_SetTitle(void* handle, const char* title);
void OpenFile_Impl_SetCurrentFolder(void* handle, const char* current_folder);
bool OpenFile_Impl_Show(void* handle, const char** result, bool modal);
```

It is expected that more properties might be added in the future to the bottom of the struct, which will make the struct grow.  However, since the struct is never passed to my library, it shouldn't introduce any ABI break if my library gets updated.  Furthermore, it doesn't seem to introduce any API break as well (barring things like explicitly asserting the struct size), since C/C++ code is not required to set all fields in the struct.

I would expect the typical call site to look like either like this:

```c
if (OpenFile({
        .result = &ptr,
        .filter_list = my_list,
        .filter_count = 4,
        .parent_window = get_native_window()})) {
    printf("Processing file %s", ptr);
    free(ptr);
}
```

or like this:

```c
OpenFileProperties props;
props.result = &ptr;
props.filter_list = my_list;
props.filter_count = 4;
props.parent_window = get_native_window();
if (OpenFile(props)) {
    printf("Processing file %s", ptr);
    free(ptr);
}
```

---

So the main question is:  Does adding new fields to the end of the `OpenFileProperties` struct constitute an ABI or API break?  If it is an API break, does it only happen in very specific situations?  (Since it would be made known to the user that more fields might be added to the struct, it is okay if most "normal" use cases won't step into ABI/API break situations.)

A side question is whether there is a better way to design such an interface.  Calling the `OpenFile_Impl_XXXX` functions directly is a possibility, but it will have at least one of these three issues, owing to the fact that the platform native API has some ordering constraints (e.g. `parent_window` having to be passed to create the dialog handle, before setting any other properties):

1. The user will have to call the `OpenFile_Impl_XXXX` functions in some specific order.  This is quite bad since different platforms have different constraints on their APIs, and I'd like to present a consistent interface to the user.
2. My library to copy all the strings passed by the user, and buffer them until the user calls `OpenFile_Impl_Show()` - this is much additional unnecessary work on the part of the library.
3. My library just stores references to those strings, which makes it easier to end up with a dangling pointer.

In addition, whichever way it goes, calling an `OpenFile_Impl_XXXX` function for every property that users want to set is much more verbose than passing in the struct.

Comment: @molbdnilo: “… if it can be used in C, it can't be a C++ API” is not a true statement. There are some APIs that can be used in C and cannot be used in C++, and there are some APIs that can be used in C++ that cannot be used in C, but it is possible to design APIs that can be used in both C and C++.

Comment: `constitute an ABI or API break?` Why do you care how it is named? Don't you care it if works instead? Let's say it is an ABI break. Or API break. Why do you care how you name it? `whether there is a better way to design such an interface` See FUSE_USE_VERSION

Comment: the most direct way is just pass a pointer (or even `void*`), make the first field some type of version info and make sure it's pointer-interconvertible with the struct. then you can just check the field and do whatever dispatch you want.

Comment: Questions about design decisions like this would be more appropriate in [softwareengineering.se]. In SO, practically anything that works is OK.

Comment: @molbdnilo There's enough in the common subset of C and C++ that one can design a header file consumable by both languages.  Such a header file usually contains `extern "C"` wrapped in an `#ifdef __cplusplus` macro to prevent C++ name mangling, and this technique has been done countless times to build real-world programs.  Obviously it may not use C++ standard library types or other C++-specific things, but the fact that my header file is valid by both the C and C++ standards, and that the emitted code is binary-compatible whether I use a C or C++ compiler makes it both a C and C++ API.

Comment: @KamilCuk I am not sure why you're talking about naming; I did not say anything in my post that suggests that the name of something affects whether it is an ABI or API break.

Comment: @appleapple That works, but I see no need to actually pass the struct to my library, so I would think I can avoid the version info thing totally.

Comment: @Bernard `Is it considered an API or ABI break` Then what is the difference between ABI and API break? Why do you care if you "consider" it "API break" or "ABI break"? I do not understand your question - "API" and "ABI", there are just names for stuff. If your code will work after adding a new struct member depends on how you use the struct, not if you consider it an "API" or "ABI" break. Or, API and ABI break names have some special meaning that relate to breaking of code. What is an "API break" and what is an "ABI break"?

Comment: `I use a C or C++ compiler` I do not follow. Are the implementation of function compiled with C or with C++? If they are compiled with C, it's C API, and C++ has a feature to import C api, just like Python or Rust or any other language have similar feature. It is not Python/Rust/C++/C API, it's just C. C++ has very different rules for objects.

Comment: @KamilCuk  The implementation of my library doesn't matter, even if I spawn python to call the native dialog, it does does not make it a Python API.  I simply mean that my header file is both valid C and valid C++ at the same time, and therefore can be included in both C and C++ source files.

Comment: For the purpose of this question, and API break is deemed to have happened if when the user of my library acquires a new version of my library (including the new header file), their code ceases to compile or starts to behave incorrectly.  An ABI break is deemed to have happened if when a new version of my library is distributed to the end user as a shared library, an application built with an older shared library starts to behave incorrectly.

Comment: The "new version of my library" is identical to the existing version except that `OpenFileProperties` contains more fields at the end, `OpenFile()` is correspondingly updated to call another public function of my library, and the public function is implemented to set the correct native property on the native dialog. You may assume that the client application does use `OpenFileProperties` with any other third-party library compiled separately, and that they don't do things like query the size of the `OpenFileProperties` struct.